# What's the recommended Weblogic 11 cleaning process to make sure an ear is deployed correctly?

Tags: java, weblogic, ear

I would like to know if there is a standarized procedure to deploy an EAR component into WebLogic 11 server.

I'm having some issues with a deployment that doesn't looks like it's working propertly.

### Server specs

**Oracle Linux server**

*Dump from "cat etc/os-release"*

```
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 6"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=6.8
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=6.8
```

**Weblogic 11 (10.3.6.0)**
**Java 1.6**

Before I'm going to deploy the EAR I do the following steps:

Stop weblogic server.
Delete cache, tmp and logs folders and his content.
Backup the old EAR.
Transfer via SFTP the new EAR.

I don't know if I'm missing something to make sure everything is in order.

Do you have any idea of what could I be missing?
I have been searching but I couldn't find any clue.

Comment: Java 1.6?  No one should be running anything older than JDK 8.  11 is production now.  You should think seriously about upgrading your JDK and app server.  Current production WL is version 12 - two years old.

Comment: For the moment we can't update because this is legacy software. 
There will be in a future a migration into GCP of this software but this is not the issue now. I have to deploy a fix and I would like to know if are some steps that I may be skipping at the moment of cleaning the Weblogic server.

Comment: I think a modern approach would automate this.  Why aren't you using something like Jenkins to check the code out of repository, build the package, and deploy it to the app server?  Sounds like you plan to sit down and do it by hand every time there's a new EAR file.

Comment: There are devops but not for development enviroment, beta and production have it.
For commercial issues we can't move to a modern approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think your list sounds okay, except for deleting the logs.  I'd prefer that you back up the logs than preserve the old EAR.

It should be possible to rebuild an EAR from the labeled branch/version in the code repository.  Backing up the EAR should only be done until the new deployment is up and running.  Once it's alive I'd delete the old EAR.

I'd recommend automating all of this.  If you're doing it by hand, it's time to follow the crowd.